# Get Public Asset Image Link From Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to generate an xml file for Google Product Feed. In the xml file I want to display a link to the product image. The code

```
image_tag("image.png")
```

works fine in my view to display the image in the browser. However I need to get the link to the asset. After running

```
rake assets:precompile
```

rails 5 generates the assets folder in my public folder with the image renamed with a hash. So going to mydomain.com/assets/image.png doesn't work However going to mydomain.com/assets/imagewithhash.png does work.

I've tried using

```
image_path("image.png")
```

to get the hashed image name but this doesn't work. This returns

```
/assets/image.png
```

instead of

```
/assets/imagewithhash.png
```

which is what I need. Can anyone help with this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here. Are you trying to generate the url to download the image?

Comment: you can get the image link with helper `image_url` or `image_path` if you don't need an absolute link. Then you can allow the user to click on the image using the helper `link_to` and first element is an `ìmage_tag` and second element is an `ìmage_url`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use 
`asset_url('my_image.png', type: :image)` or `image_url('my_image.png')` to get the hashed URL for your assets.

If it is not giving you the hash after the asset then Rails did not find that asset.  Either you have a typo in your string or the asset does not exist.
`image_url('my_iamge.png')` will link to `localhost:3000/assets/my_iamge.png`
So double check those if you are still not getting the compiled asset you expect.